# How does mimamsa explain the existence of humans?

Tags: human, mimamsa

How does mimamsa explain the existence of humans.

Do they take the verses about manu literary or do they believe that humans came after evolution. 
Or 
Do mimamsa believes that humans existed co-eternaly with the universe or they are non eternal. And came after the universe.

Comment: Mimamsa follow the vedas. The Upanishads state how humans came. See Aitareya Upanishad for 1 example and Gaudapada's Karika on the Mandukya Upanishad

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda sir can you quote the verse number. And can you tell if they believe that humans are also eternal along with the universe